# customised bootstrap not showing resposive behaviour in tablets

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drupal-7, responsive-design, drupal-themes

I used **Customised twitter bootstrap framework** for theming a Drupal site. It gave me two files

```
bootstrap.css 

bootstrap.min.css.
```

When I uploaded the simple theme (Not Drupal)  it was showing responsive behavior in tablets . I converted the same theme to Drupal, the drupal site shows responsive behavior when  I resize the browser in my computer. But when I visit the site in a tablet, it comes as a normal website, not a responsive one.

This is the hierarchy of css files in theme.info.

```
stylesheets[all][] = css/bootstrap.css

stylesheets[all][] = css/bootstrap.min.css

stylesheets[all][] = css/custom.css
```

Where am I going wrong? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're not including the responsive stylesheet, you're just including the main bootstrap stylesheet (`bootstrap.css`, used for development) and the minified version (`bootstrap.min.css`, user for production). Just remove the `bootstrap.css` stylesheet and include the responsive sheet after, [`bootstrap-responsive.css`](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css).

Comment: Thank you for response @Andres. Since I downloaded the customized version of bootstrap,  I got only two files bootstrap.css and bootstrap.min.css and I was told that bootstrap-responsive.css is included in bootstrap.css in customized version. In fact it was included in bootstrap.css. And I can also see the responsive behavior while resizing the browser, but I dont see this behavior in tablets.

Comment: @sandeshyadav Oh, did not that was being done now with the customized download :P Do you have a demo site so i can check out your page and diagnose the issue?

Comment: for now the site can be seen at http://bibliophilics.com/test/writerskafe/            and I am using the customised download .

Comment: @sandeshyadav try adding the following meta to the header of your page, `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: Thank you andres. Since I dont have access to tablet now, I will check that after some time and tell you if that works.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't have to include both files.

and second you have to use some classes to make the behaviour responsive. As far as i know there is no bootstrap-responsive file (a dedicated file) because bootstrap itself supports responsiveness.

e.g. if u want to make the tables reponsive, use class="table-responsive" along with other classes. if u want to make buttons responsive use class=" col-lg-* col-md-* col-sm-* col-xs-*"
where * stands for digit rangin from 1 to 12. This is called grid system.